# ¿Cómo crear una tabla en html a partir de una relación entre tablas de PostgreSQL?

Tags: angular9

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas entre sí en una base de datos PostgreSQL, una tabla es de especies de verdura (Especie) y la otra de meses de siembra (MesSiembra). Donde una especie tiene muchos meses de siembra y un mes tiene muchas especies. Quisiera generar un calendario en "html" por medio de una tabla tal que quede similar a la imagen adjunta, donde cada mes de siembra de una especie en particular esté representada por el símbolo "●" (círculo negro) y el mes sin sembrar esté vacío (sin relación). Estoy usando TypeScript para programar el front-end. Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y tal vez me falte detallar algo en mi pregunta. Cualquier cosa me preguntan. Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí algo de código:

**calendario.component.html**

```
<h1>CALENDARIO DE SIEMBRA</h1>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Especie</th>
      <th scope="col">Ene.</th>
      <th scope="col">Feb.</th>
      <th scope="col">Mar.</th>
      <th scope="col">Abr.</th>
      <th scope="col">May.</th>
      <th scope="col">Jun.</th>
      <th scope="col">Jul.</th>
      <th scope="col">Ago.</th>
      <th scope="col">Sep.</th>
      <th scope="col">Oct.</th>
      <th scope="col">Nov.</th>
      <th scope="col">Dic.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let e of especies">
      <td>{{e.nombre}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**calendario.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Especie, EspecieService } from 'src/app/servicios/especie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendario',
  templateUrl: './calendario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendario.component.css']
})
export class CalendarioComponent implements OnInit {
  especies: Especie[] = [];
  
  constructor(private _servicioEspecie: EspecieService,
    private _router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._servicioEspecie.get().subscribe(respuesta => {
      console.log(respuesta);
      this.especies = respuesta;
    });
  }    
}
```

En el código html pude mostrar los nombres de las especies pero no logro mostrar los meses.

Respuesta obtenida con un GET a Especies con Postman. Códico JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 49,
        "nombre": "Berenjena",
        "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/C6xxY0w/Berenjena.jpg",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-24T03:27:19.139+00:00",
        "descripcion": "La berenjena (Solanum melongena) es una planta de fruto comestible, generalmente anual, del género Solanum dentro de la familia de las solanáceas.",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 15,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 20,
        "distEntrePlantas": 40,
        "distEntreLineas": 70,
        "familia": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "Solanáceas",
            "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/F4BbJQK/Solan-ceas.jpg",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:16:34.638+00:00",
            "descripcion": "Las solanáceas son una familia de plantas herbáceas con las hojas alternas, simples y sin estípulas pertenecientes al orden Solanales, de las dicotiledóneas.​",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nombre": "Julio"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "nombre": "Septiembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "nombre": "Octubre"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 61,
        "nombre": "Cebolla",
        "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/BPFgMbm/Cebolla.jpg",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-27T17:15:38.235+00:00",
        "descripcion": "Allium cepa, comúnmente conocida como cebolla, es una planta herbácea bienal perteneciente a la familia de las amarilidáceas. Es la especie más cultivada del género Allium, el cual contiene varias especies que se denominan «cebollas» y que se cultivan como alimento. Ejemplos de las mismas son la cebolla de verdeo (Allium fistulosum), la cebolla escalonia (Allium ascalonicum) y la cebolla de hoja o ciboulette (Allium schoenoprasum).",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 10,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 25,
        "distEntrePlantas": 10,
        "distEntreLineas": 35,
        "familia": {
            "id": 31,
            "nombre": "Liliáceas",
            "linkImagen": "aaaaaaaaaab",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-10T03:30:39.756+00:00",
            "descripcion": "fdghjkl",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nombre": "Febrero"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "nombre": "Marzo"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "nombre": "Abril"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "nombre": "Mayo"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "nombre": "Junio"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nombre": "Julio"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 66,
        "nombre": "Pimiento",
        "linkImagen": "trghreth",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-29T19:36:37.307+00:00",
        "descripcion": "erytyhjdrthyftyj",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 10,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 20,
        "distEntrePlantas": 20,
        "distEntreLineas": 40,
        "familia": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "Solanáceas",
            "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/F4BbJQK/Solan-ceas.jpg",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:16:34.638+00:00",
            "descripcion": "Las solanáceas son una familia de plantas herbáceas con las hojas alternas, simples y sin estípulas pertenecientes al orden Solanales, de las dicotiledóneas.​",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "nombre": "Septiembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "nombre": "Octubre"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "nombre": "Noviembre"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "nombre": "Tomate",
        "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/2F6fPw2/Tomate.jpg",
        "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:23:23.103+00:00",
        "descripcion": "Solanum lycopersicum, cuyo fruto es el tomate, conocida comúnmente como tomatera, es una especie de planta herbácea del género Solanum de la familia Solanaceae.​​",
        "dtype": "Especie",
        "diasGerminacionDesde": 5,
        "diasGerminacionHasta": 8,
        "distEntrePlantas": 30,
        "distEntreLineas": 80,
        "familia": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "Solanáceas",
            "linkImagen": "https://i.ibb.co/F4BbJQK/Solan-ceas.jpg",
            "fechaRegistro": "2020-08-08T06:16:34.638+00:00",
            "descripcion": "Las solanáceas son una familia de plantas herbáceas con las hojas alternas, simples y sin estípulas pertenecientes al orden Solanales, de las dicotiledóneas.​",
            "dtype": "Familia"
        },
        "mesesSiembra": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nombre": "Julio"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "nombre": "Agosto"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "nombre": "Septiembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "nombre": "Octubre"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "nombre": "Noviembre"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "nombre": "Diciembre"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Ah bien, comprendo lo que me dices, hace poco empecé a programar y soy nuevo en el sitio, algunas dudas que tenía las he resuelto mirando otras preguntas y no sabía como encuadrar la mía para que logren entenderme. Más luego agrego parte del código que tengo escrito y voy a leer el "Cómo preguntar" así puedo realizar mejores preguntas futuras.

Comment: Aquí unas recomendaciones para tener preguntas de mayor chance de obtener respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Puse el ultimo angular, pero ni idea que version estas usando.. TS es obligatorio en angular, tu codigo no es TS... Una recomandacion, te vas a volver loco tratando de hacerlo asi.. lee todas las plantas con su mes.. y luego, construi una matriz con marcas, y dibuja la tabla segun esas marcas...

Comment: La versión de Angular que estoy usando es la 9.1.12

Comment: Coloca el resultado de `console.log(respuesta);`

Comment: Perdón, el resultado de qué sería? de la versión de angular?

Comment: Tu consultas tu API y te trae los resultados de la query. Estos resultados se deberian mostrar en consola cuando haces `console.log(respuesta);`, esa respuesta que seguro es un JSON te pido que la publiques

Comment: Ahí agregué el JSON de la respuesta a Especies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo `.ts` creas un array con los meses y una función que retorne si `mesesSiembra` tiene el mes correspondiente

```
meses : string[] = ["Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dic"];
tieneMes(meses : any[],index:number) : boolean{
    return meses.some(a => a.id == index + 1 );
 }
```

En el archivo `.css` creas un estilo para el circulo

```
.circulo{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Y en el archivo `.html` colocas:

```
<h1>CALENDARIO DE SIEMBRA</h1>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Especies</th>
      <th *ngFor="let m of meses">{{m}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let e of especies">
      <td>{{e.nombre}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let m of meses;index as i">
        <div class="{{tieneMes(e.mesesSiembra,i)?'circulo':''}}"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]